# Google Cloud Spring Boot NoSuchFileException

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've attempted to deploy a spring-boot app to google cloud. It runs fine locally, however when deploying it to App Engine I get a large amount of NoSuchFileException's:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /workspace/lib/modelmapper-2.3.5.jar
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:149) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1239) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:348) ~[na:na]
```

I also get errors stating that I have over 10000 files but my application has nowhere near 10000 files. I suspect it is including files from libraries or other things referenced in my pom.xml (or imports? I'm not sure how gcloud functions in this regard honestly.)

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>samuelB</groupId>
    <artifactId>capripol</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Capripol</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- <properties>
    

    
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

      
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>

        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <nohttp-checkstyle.version>0.0.4.RELEASE</nohttp-checkstyle.version>
        <spring-format.version>0.0.25</spring-format.version> -->
    <!-- </properties> -->

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
      <!-- Use Spring Milestone Repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>samuelb.capripol.CapripolApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CapripolApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CapripolApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CapripolApplication.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/", "classpath:/images/") //tells Spring the location of resources
                    .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the main method.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra i have now added

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are using java.nio.file package and this path "/workspace/lib/modelmapper-2.3.5.jar" ?